# Fetching image from database into Android GridView

Tags: android, database, gridview

I am trying to fetch a text and image link from the database and add it to an ArrayList and then use it to display the text and image in a grid view. But it doesn't show up. It seems like the list items seem to be null when I try to add it.

What am I missing? I have gone through some answers and wasn't able to figure it out.

```
public final class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static final String showUrl = "http://netbigs.com/apps/fetch.php";
String myJSON;
public String mvname;
String mvinfo;
public String rdate,imglink;

private Context mContext;
private final List<Item> mItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;



private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "result";
private static final String TAG_ID = "mvid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "mvname";
private static final String TAG_IMG = "imglink";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "rdate";
private static final String TAG_MOVINF = "mvinfo";

JSONArray movies = null;


public GridAdapter(Context context) {

    mItems.add(new Item(mvname,imglink));
    mContext=context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int i) {
    return mItems.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = view;
    ImageView picture;
    TextView name;
    getData();




    if (v == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
        v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
    }

    picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
    name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.text);

    Item item = getItem(i);


    Picasso.with(this.mContext).load(item.drawableId).into(picture);

    name.setText(item.name);
    System.out.println(item.name);

    return v;
}

private static class Item {
    public final String name;
    public final String drawableId;

    Item(String name, String drawableId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.drawableId = drawableId;
    }
}

protected void showList(){


    try{
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        movies = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for (int i=0;i<movies.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = movies.getJSONObject(i);
            String mvid = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            mvname = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            System.out.println(mvname);

            imglink = c.getString(TAG_IMG);
            System.out.println(imglink);

            rdate = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
            mvinfo = c.getString(TAG_MOVINF);
            try {



            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }




    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public void getData(){
    class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String uri = showUrl;
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                inputStream = con.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                return sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            myJSON=result;
            showList();
        }
    }
    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
    g.execute();
}
}
```

This is the fragment to which the GridAdapter is attached.

```
public class MovieFragment extends Fragment {


public MovieFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movie, container, false);

    GridView gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(getActivity()));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i;
            switch (position){

                case 0:

                    i = new Intent(MovieFragment.this.getActivity(),MovieDetail.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    i = new Intent(MovieFragment.this.getActivity(),MovieDetail.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    i = new Intent(MovieFragment.this.getActivity(),MovieDetail.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    i = new Intent(MovieFragment.this.getActivity(),MovieDetail.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;



            }


        }
    });

    return view;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}



@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
}
```

Comment: You should add data in list in for loop of showList()  method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `getData()` from your Adapter so it may possible that when you initialize it at that time your list is null.

Try calling that method form your activity or fragment and then pass the received data you received in your adapter class.

`getView()` is called multiple time when you scroll up or down so never call any api in that method

Provide the code where you are using this adapter.

Comment: I have added the fragment code in which the adapter is used.

Comment: you have to put getData() and showList() and then after receiving the response you have to make one list of the records and pas that list in your adapter constructor it will work.

Comment: Thanks,that fixed it.Also where should i call the api?

Comment: you can call it anywhere in your fragment class but be careful that either you initialize adapter and set to gridview after receiving the data or you can notifyDatasetChanged() after receiving the data

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are not getting values from the DB.

you must get the values from the db first. by using Volley or some plugin  like that(or Aysnc task. volley will be better i think.)

Comment: The values are correctly fetched,but i can't figure out where i should place the getdata().